# WPF ListView binding with custom type & Insert controls

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding

I'm making chat program and I already made API to connect server.

And this is a core class for API

```
public partial class PengChat3ClientSock : IDisposable
```

Well, `PengChat3ClientSock` has a `Rooms` property.

```
public class Room
{
    public uint ID { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public string Master { get; internal set; }

    public short MaxConnectorNum { get; private set; }

    public bool IsNeedPassword { get; private set; }
}
```

And this is a Rooms property

```
public Room[] Rooms { get; private set; }
```

Now the client, I have ListView which is showing room list.

```
<ListView x:Name="listView_RoomList" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
</ListView>
```

And i want to design listview like this.

```
RoomName Master MaxConnectorNum Password(If IsNeedPassword is true = Enable) EntryButton   DeleteButton(If Master is I = Enable)
Label    Label  Label           PasswordBox                                  Button        Button
Label    Label  Label           PasswordBox                                  Button        Button
Label    Label  Label           PasswordBox                                  Button        Button
Label    Label  Label           PasswordBox                                  Button        Button
```

The top is headers.
and i want to insert controls like this.

And if property `Rooms` changed, i want to change this `ListView` automatically.

Is it too hard? but i think it is possible.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: *Is it too hard?*... no, it's fairly standard. *i want to change this ListView automatically*... yes, we all want our code to write itself, but it won't so you'll have to do it. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Sheridan hmm.. i tried so many solutions. such as GridView.. but i could not get good output. Now i'm mobile. tomorrow i will upload code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have not misunderstood your question Try this

> Room.cs

```
public class Room
{
    public uint ID { get;  set; }

    public string Name { get;  set; }

    public string Master { get;  set; }

    public short MaxConnectorNum { get;  set; }

    public bool IsNeedPassword { get;  set; }
}
```

> xaml

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="deleteButtonStyle">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"></Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Master}" Value="I">
                <DataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger.Setters>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Rooms}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="RoomName">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Label Content="Label"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Master">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Label Content="Label"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="MaxConnectorNum">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Label Content="Label"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Password">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <PasswordBox IsEnabled="{Binding IsNeedPassword }" MinWidth="100"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="EntryButton">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Content="Button"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="DeleteButton">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Content="Button" Style="{StaticResource deleteButtonStyle}">
                                </Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

> xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext=new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

> ViewModel

```
    public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Room> Rooms { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Rooms = new ObservableCollection<Room>() 
        {
            new Room(){Master="I",IsNeedPassword=false},
            new Room(){Master="I",IsNeedPassword=true},
            new Room(){Master="j",IsNeedPassword=false},
            new Room(){Master="k",IsNeedPassword=true}
        };
    }
}
```

> output
>   [image]